# <timestamp>_add_devise_to_users.rb created instead of <timestamp>_devise_create_users.rb

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am absolute new to Ruby on rails and was running the following command
$rails generate devise user

I expected the file _devise_create_users.rb to be generated . However its generating the file _add_devise_to_users.rb.
So when i run the command rake db:migrate after this, it gives me an error , SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL. since there is no user table created.

Any headways suggested ?

Comment: you need to create `users` table first. then migrate the database. and then you can run the `rails generate devise user`

Comment: Thanks Andrey. that worked..first rails generate model User name:string email:string and then executed the migrate command..perfect

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to capitalize User

```
rails generate devise User
```

Make sure you rollback any mistakes you made to the db in your prior attempts.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to not recognize the "devise" gem, as if thinking "devise" is a column name, and "user" is the table to add the column to. Ensure "devise" is present in your Gemfile.

You can also verify if the "devise" gem is installed with `$ gem list` in a shell inside your Rails project folder.